# how can we change the DISPLAY variable in linux

Tags: environment-variables, variable, display

What is the command to change the DISPLAY display variable in Linux, because while installation of a program I am getting the error as in the attached screen shot, so please help me how to get it out from over there.
[image: [error which triggered to me]

Comment: The `DISPLAY` variable is set automatically in a normal GUI session. If it isn't set, you are not in a normal GUI session, and setting the variable manually is unlikely to help. What kind of a machine is this? How are you logging in?

Comment: its a Virtual machine created with oracle linux7 os and i am logging in as oracle user only.

Comment: How are you logging in? Over the network from another machine? If so what OS is that machine running? At a text mode prompt? In a graphical screen in the VM?

Answer (score 1):

There's no screenshot, but if I understand you correctly you can do something like `export DISPLAY=:0`